# How to manipulate placeholder plugin of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, placeholder

I am using [Placeholder](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder) plugin of `CKEditor` to put wild card variables. Now I want to change the text being rendered together with default enclosure of the placeholder which is the `[[]]`. I want to change it to `{{}}` to look like `{{placeholder}}` instead of `[[placeholder]]`. How can I possibly manipulate the source code?

I already tried to manipulate the `plugin.js`:

```
editor.widgets.add( 'placeholder', {
                // Widget code.
                dialog: 'placeholder',
                pathName: lang.pathName,
                // We need to have wrapping element, otherwise there are issues in
                // add dialog.
                template: '<span class="cke_placeholder">{{}}</span>',

                downcast: function() {
                    return new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text( '{{' + this.data.name + '}}' );
                },

                init: function() {
                    // Note that placeholder markup characters are stripped for the name.
                    this.setData( 'name', this.element.getText().slice( 2, -2 ) );
                },

                data: function() {
                    this.element.setText( '{{' + this.data.name + '}}' );
                }
            } );
```

But there's no effect on the editor. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Correction:**
The Regular expression should be:

```
var placeholderReplaceRegex = /\{\{([^{}])+\}\}/g;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Firstly, did your placeholder plugin work with default enclosure [[]]?

I tested out in http://www.regextester.com and http://scriptular.com/ sites then also tested in my  ckeditor placeholder plugin for below text
"Test {{FirstName}} and {{LastName}} this is a new string"

Comment: Firstly, did your placeholder plugin work with default enclosure [[]]?

I tested out in http://www.regextester.com and http://scriptular.com/ sites then also tested in my  ckeditor placeholder plugin for below text
"Test {{FirstName}} and {{LastName}} this is a new string" 
Matched strings are:
{{FirstName}}
{{LastName}}

Comment: when I try these corrections, I have "Cannot read property '{' of undefined". as of now, I'm not sure this change can be implemented anymore

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to modify the regular expression in afterInit function , see below example

```
afterInit: function( editor ) {
        //var placeholderReplaceRegex = /\[\[([^\[\]])+\]\]/g;
        var placeholderReplaceRegex = /\{\{({^\{\}})+\}\}/g;
        editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
            text: function( text, node ) {
                var dtd = node.parent && CKEDITOR.dtd[ node.parent.name ];

                // Skip the case when placeholder is in elements like <title> or <textarea>
                // but upcast placeholder in custom elements (no DTD).
                if ( dtd && !dtd.span )
                    return;

                return text.replace( placeholderReplaceRegex, function( match ) {
                    // Creating widget code.
                    var widgetWrapper = null,
                        innerElement = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element( 'span', {
                            'class': 'cke_placeholder'
                        } );

                    // Adds placeholder identifier as innertext.
                    innerElement.add( new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text( match ) );
                    widgetWrapper = editor.widgets.wrapElement( innerElement, 'placeholder' );

                    // Return outerhtml of widget wrapper so it will be placed
                    // as replacement.
                    return widgetWrapper.getOuterHtml();
                } );
            }
        } );
    }
```